# Node JS Request external API and send it back to client side AJAX

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ajax, api

So I have a Node.js server that route does one thing. When called by a button click on client side, it goes here and fetches data from external API.

```
app.get('/ajaxcall', function(req, res) {
const options = {
    url: 'hidden url',
    method: 'POST',
};

request(options, function(err, request, body) {
    if (err) {
        request.send('There was an error with fetching API');
    }
    else {
        console.log(res.statusCode);
        return res.end(JSON.stringify(body));
    }
});
});
```

Then I have this bit that goes and fetches this data from the server.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#searchButton').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault()
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/ajaxcall',
})
.done(function(result){
  let data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
  console.log(data)
  console.log(data[0].formatted_address)
})
.fail(function(xhr, status, error){
  console.log(error)
})
.always(function(data){})
})
})
```

The thing is that `console.log(data)` will output everything into the console, but `console.log(data.[0].formatted_address)`outputs undefined.

I am trying to grab data from this JSON that I get back, so I can display it on the website. Can anyone tell me why console.log(formatted_address) does not work on client side, but works on server side? Is there a way to loop through this JSON object and pick bits I need?

Here's how the JSON look
[JSON screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfBYp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to change the .done function to loop though some of the data using the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) array function.

```
.done(function(result){
  let data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

  data.results.forEach(function(result) {
        console.log(result.formatted_address);
        console.log(result.geometry.location.lat, result.geometry.location.lng);
        console.log(result.icon);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON you posted is what is deserialized into the `data` variable on the front-end, it seems like `data` is a JSON object that contains a `results` field which is an array instead of the `data` object itself being an array.

Try something like `data.results[0].formatted_address`